# Loading Pixbuf to Image Widget in GTK#

Tags: c#, monodevelop, gtk#

I'm trying to load an image file from harddisk to the image widget in GTK#.I know that Pixbuf is used to represent the image.In .net i had used `Bitmap b=Bitmap.from File ("c:\windows\file.jpg")`

and assigned `PictureBox=b`;

How can i do this with `Image Widget`

Update:

I tried

```
protected void OnButton2ButtonPressEvent (object o, ButtonPressEventArgs args)
    {
        var buffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes ("i:\\Penguins.jpg");
        var pixbuf = new Gdk.Pixbuf (buffer);
        image103.Pixbuf = pixbuf;

   }
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var buffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes ("path\\to\\file");
var pixbuf = new Gdk.Pixbuf (buffer);
image.Pixbuf = pixbuf;
```

Also you may create a pixbuf like this:

```
var pixbuf = new Gdk.Pixbuf ("path\\to\\file");
```

But when I tried to use this constructor with path containing some russian symbols I had an exception because of wrong encoding.

**Update**
I don't know any legacy method to set in gtk# image stretch option and I usually solve this problem with creation of new control. So right click on the project->Add->Create Widget and set the name to **ImageControl**. Add **Image** on created widget. Then edit **ImageControl**'s code like this:

```
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem (true)]
public partial class ImageControl : Gtk.Bin
{

    private Pixbuf original;

    private bool resized;

    public Gdk.Pixbuf Pixbuf {
        get
        { 
            return image.Pixbuf;
        }
        set
        { 
            original = value;
            image.Pixbuf = value;
        }
    }

    public ImageControl ()
    {
        this.Build ();
    }
    protected override void OnSizeAllocated (Gdk.Rectangle allocation)
    {
        if ((image.Pixbuf != null) && (!resized)) {
            var srcWidth = original.Width;
            var srcHeight = original.Height;
            int resultWidth, resultHeight;
            ScaleRatio (srcWidth, srcHeight, allocation.Width, allocation.Height, out resultWidth, out resultHeight);
            image.Pixbuf = original.ScaleSimple (resultWidth, resultHeight, InterpType.Bilinear);
            resized = true;
        } else {
            resized = false;
            base.OnSizeAllocated (allocation);
        }
    }

    private static void ScaleRatio(int srcWidth, int srcHeight, int destWidth, int destHeight, out int resultWidth, out int resultHeight)
    {
        var widthRatio = (float)destWidth / srcWidth;
        var heigthRatio = (float)destHeight / srcHeight;

        var ratio = Math.Min(widthRatio, heigthRatio);
        resultHeight = (int)(srcHeight * ratio);
        resultWidth = (int)(srcWidth * ratio);
    }
}
```

Now you may set pictures with **Pixbuf** property of **ImageControl**'s widget.

Comment: @techno What means "doesn't work"? Do you have an exception or your control just not updated?

Comment: @techno Just tested this code and have no problems. Did you set WidthRequest/HeightRequest properties? Make sure that your image is visible. You may set default image through the window designer.

Comment: No I did not set those properties.I have used the Button On Pressed Signal

Comment: It works now,i did not add the code to button clicked.Instead i added it to Widget Clicked

Comment: Is there a way to set the image widget to fit the image like we set the stretch property in winforms

Comment: @techno I updated the answer according to your question about stretch.

Comment: Thanks a lot,i wish GTK# had better widgets like winforms.

Comment: @Yeah :) Same is the case with Winforms Support.Have you tried compiling any winforms project(with designer.cs created by visual studio) using Mono compiler(on windows),it creates a exe in my case.But when i try to run it using mono file.exe some exceptions  popup

Comment: @techno I tied. Winforms have bad implementation in mono. There are a lot of methods which aren't even existed, windows looks not native and there is some problems with colors. If you want a real cross platform application on .NET use ASP.NET MVC technology - browser is all that you need.

Comment: Can you help me with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511014/showing-font-selection-dialog-in-gtk

Comment: @Deffiss : I found a bug in your code: You only call the "base.OnSizeAllocated" if youre not resizing, it should be called everytime. In my case it lead to a bug, that the ExposeEvent of the object has not been called.