# Showing Font Selection Dialog in GTK#

Tags: c#, fonts, mono, monodevelop, gtk#

In MY gtk# Application im trying to show the font selection dialog.Im trying to use the following code,but the FontSelectionDialog constructor need some arguments also does the control execution wait for a font to be selected to set the string `font`

Can someone guide me?

```
Gtk.FontSelectionDialog fs = new FontSelectionDialog()
            fs.Show ();
            font=fs.FontName;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated according to additional question**

This should help:

```
FontSelectionDialog dialog = null;
try {
    dialog = new FontSelectionDialog("Choose a font");
    dialog.Run ();
    var name = dialog.FontName;
    var pattern = @"^(?<fontName>.*)\s(?<fontSize>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$";
    var regex = new Regex(pattern);
    var match = regex.Match(name);
    if(match.Success)
    {
        var fontName = match.Groups["fontName"].Value;
        var fontSize = float.Parse(match.Groups["fontSize"].Value);
        var font = new System.Drawing.Font(fontName, fontSize);
    }
} finally {
    if (dialog != null)
        dialog.Destroy ();
}
```

Comment: @techno No problems friend.

Comment: If i use the FontButton Provided by GTK# like this 'font = fontbutton1.FontName;',how can i get the font size? My aim is to create a Font Object from the font selected by the user

Comment: @techno Do you mean Gdk.Font object or something else? And what you want to do with it?

Comment: I had used a font object(System.drawing) to draw a text with the desired  font.So i want to create the font object

Comment: @techno I should say that it isn't good decision to mix Winform and Gtk but It's your choice. I think best option in this case is to use regex. See my updated answer (don't remember to add reference on System.Drawing.dll).

Comment: This method does not work.The Font name is not returned

Comment: @techno It's impossible because I tested it and successfully created System.Drawing.Font object.